# How to iterate properly over the search results of a DMultiMap (DeCAL) in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, decal

I am using the DMultiMap container from [DeCAL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/decal/) with Delphi 6 to store data. The key is a string which can appears several time in the map.

I wonder how to iterate properly over all objects with a given key.

Will this code:

```
function IterateOverObjects(map: DMultimap);
var iter: DIterator;
begin
  iter := map.locate(['abc']);
  while IterateOver(iter) do
  begin
    // do something with the value...
  end;
end;
```

returns all the objects of with 'abc' as key? Or will it returns all the objects of the map starting from the first object with 'abc' as key?

**Edit:** Just tested. It returns all the objects of the map starting from the first object with 'abc' as key. What is then the best way to iterate over 'abc'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: tested version (I've changed previously used findif, because I investigated that it doesn't use fast locate, it just loops through all the items):

EDIT2: because my previous test was bad, I've edited function to make it work properly. it looks almost the same as Name's answer, but I changed it to not confuse anyone with incorrect function.

```
    function IterateOverFound(Map: DMultiMap; var iter: DIterator; const obj: array of const): Boolean;
begin
  if diIteration in iter.flags then
  begin
    advance(iter);
    SetToKey(iter);
    iter := findIn(iter, Map.finish, obj);
  end
  else
  begin
    iter := Map.locate(obj);
    Include(iter.flags, diIteration);
  end;

  Result := not atEnd(iter);
  if not result then
    Exclude(iter.flags, diIteration);
end;
```

Example usage:

```
var
  iter: DIterator;

  iter := map.start; 
  while IterateOverFound(map, iter, ['abc']) do
  begin
    SetToValue(iter);
    // get value
  end;
```

Comment: Thanks. I like the syntax. But 2 problems: it stays indefinitely on the same item and a call of SetToKey is missing. I have added a corrected version of the function in your post, but it will visible only after it is peer reviewed.

Comment: @Name: You should just post the corrected version as a separate answer :)

Comment: The edited version (the one using locate) doesn't work properly. I'm testing with a map containing followings values: 'aaa' => 0, 'def' => 1,, 'abc' => 2, 'abc' => 3, 'def' => 4, 'abc' => 5, 'def' => 6 and I get 2, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6. (But I must say that my corrected version didn't work properly either. I'll try to correct it and post it as a new answer)

Answer (score 1):

In the meanwhile I made some researches and found one solution. As DMultiMap is an ordered map (based on a black tree and not on an hash value), all items with the same key are grouped so that following code works:

```
function IterateOverObjects(map: DMultimap);
var iter1, iter2: DIterator;
begin
  iter1 := map.locate(['abc']);
  if not AtEnd(iter1) then
  begin
    iter2 := map.upper_bound(['abc']);
    repeat
      // do something with the value...
      Advance(iter1);
    until equals(iter1, iter2);
  end;
end;
```

Another possibility would be:

```
function IterateOverObjects(map: DMultimap);
var iter: DIterator;
begin
  iter := map.locate(['abc']);
  while IterateOver(iter) do
  begin
    SetToKey(iter);
    if (getString(iter) <> 'abc') then break;
    SetToValue(iter);
    // do something with the value...
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the syntax of the usage example proposed by Linas, but as the function doesn't work properly, here is a corrected version. The fact that FindIn doesn't use a fast locate isn't a problem, as it is only used to iterate (A DMultiMap is an ordered map, so that all items with the same key are together):

```
function IterateOverFound(Map: DMultiMap; var iter: DIterator; const obj: array of const): Boolean;
var bWasToKey: boolean;
begin
  if diIteration in iter.flags then
  begin
    advance(iter);
    bWasToKey := diKey in iter.flags;
    SetToKey(iter);
    iter := DeCAL.findIn(iter, DeCAL.getContainer(iter).finish, obj);
    if not bWasToKey then
      SetToValue(iter);
  end else
  begin
    iter := Map.locate(obj);
    Include(iter.flags, diIteration);
  end;
  result := not atEnd(iter);
  if not result then
    Exclude(iter.flags, diIteration);
end;
```

Example usage:

```
var
  map: DMultiMap;
  iter: DIterator;

map := DMultiMap.Create;
map.putPair(['aaa', 0]);
map.putPair(['def', 1]);
map.putPair(['abc', 2]);
map.putPair(['abc', 3]);
map.putPair(['def', 4]);
map.putPair(['abc', 5]);
map.putPair(['def', 6]);
iter := map.start;
while IterateOverFound(map, iter, ['abc']) do
begin
  // do something with the value...
end;
```

Comment: This version is OK. My test case was bas previously :) One thing: you dont need to call getContainer(iter) in findin, because you have map as a parameter.